# How can I save current router into a state?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm trying to use 2 different headers. I just need to save the current router page into a state. so I can implement conditional styling. something like this

```js
 const [page, setPage] = useState("black");

  const data = {
    page,
    setPage,
  };


// SOMETHING LIKE THIS BUT THIS DOESN'T WORK //
const ACTIVEPAGE: any = {
  "/": setPage("black),
  "/projects/project/[id]": setPage("black),
  "/404": setPage("black),
  "/booking": setPage("black),
  "/teammembers": setPage("black),
  "/projects": setPage("white),
  "/singlecareers": setPage("white),
  "/careers": setPage("white),
  "/aboutus": setPage("white),
  "/news": setPage("white),
  "/news/[id]": setPage("white),
};
};


  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <MainContext.Provider value={data}>
      <Header />
      {children}
      <Footer />
    </MainContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to save current route in the state, you can make the condition on `router.asPath` base like: `router.asPath === "/404" ? "white" : "black"` also here you can see the example on [this link](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router), also as you can see the below code.

```
  const childPaths = ["/", "/projects/project", "/404", "/teammembers"]

  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <MainContext.Provider value={data}>
      <Header className={childPaths.includes(router.asPath) ? "black" : "white"} />
      {children}
      <Footer />
    </MainContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

Or also you can do like this:

```
const ACTIVEPAGE = {
    "/": "black",
    "/projects/project": "white",
    "/404": "white",
  };


  const router = useRouter();

  // you can see the values on console
  console.log("router.asPath", router.asPath)
  console.log("ACTIVEPAGE[router.asPath]", ACTIVEPAGE[router.asPath])

  return (
    <MainContext.Provider value={data}>
      <Header className={`${ACTIVEPAGE[router.asPath]}`} />
      {children}
      <Footer />
    </MainContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

let say this is you header component, you can do like this instead of passing props:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

import Logo1 from '../assets......';
import Logo2 from '../assets......';

const Header = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const childPaths = ["/", "/projects/project", "/404", "/teammembers"];

  return (
    <>
    {childPaths.includes(router.asPath) ? <img src={Logo1} /> : <img src={Logo2} />}
    </>
  )

}

export default Header;
```

If you want to pass the props in header component you can do like this:

```
const childPaths = ["/", "/projects/project", "/404", "/teammembers"]

  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <MainContext.Provider value={data}>
      <Header paths={childPaths} />
      {children}
      <Footer />
    </MainContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

then you can get the props in header component, you can see the below code

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

import Logo1 from '../assets......';
import Logo2 from '../assets......';

const Header = ({paths}) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  return (
    <>
     {paths.includes(router.asPath) ? <img src={Logo1} /> : <img src={Logo2} />}
    </>
  )

}

export default Header;
```

Comment: thank you but I have so many route links. so I just need to pass "black" state into child components then I can use something like this while styling the header component. {className={black ? "navbar" : "navbar2"}

Comment: I have updated the answer, If you have multiple routes, you can see the above code,  I make the array of routes which you assign `black` color, when you are in this route navbar color will be `black` or else 'white'. and also by default `white`.

Comment: thanks again I think I need to pass with props. black white is just an example it can be true or false. one header's logo is different for example. so I can pass this into the header component then use like this {setPage ? thislogo : otherlogo}.

Comment: yes you can do like this `{page ? logo1 : logo2}`

Comment: sorry I'm struggling a bit. how can I pass your first solution as props instead of giving a className.

Comment: I have updated the answer, you can see the last three `code blocks`, I hope this would be helpful :)

Comment: If you have prop `page` you can pass the `page` as `prop` like: `<Header page={page} />`.

Comment: amazing work thank you! also just noticed you're the same guy that helped me before. ^^

Comment: Yeah, Thankyou, I will be happy to help you again :)